# Show/Hide Table Rows with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an array of prices that I output to a table with a `foreach` loop.

I'm trying to figure out how to hide rows in the table if a condition is met.  The `$status` variable evaluates to *"YES"* if price is `=> 30` and *"NO"* if `< 30`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function displayRow(){
    var row = document.getElementById("<?php echo $status;?>");
    if (row.id == 'YES')  row.id= 'none';
    else row.display = '';
  }
</script>

<?php
  if($price > 30.00){
    $status = "YES";
  }else if($price < 30.00){
    $status = "NO";
  }

  $prices = array ("20", "56", "33", "12", "66", "25", "55");
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  foreach ($prices as $price) {
    echo "<tr id='$status'><td>$price</td></tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table>";
?>

<button onclick="displayRow()" >Show / Hide</button>
```

I've tried setting the `tr` `id` with the appropriate status.  So then in the Javascript function I try to pass the `$status` in to `getElementById` which should then display the prices that are `>` than `30` and hide those that are `< 30`.
The button is meant to toggle between display all the data or filter those prices `> 30`.

I know this is a very basic example and have probably made a lot of mistakes, but I'd appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: That won`t work, this code is so bad... First of all <?php echo $status;?> returns nothing, second in your if($price) $price is not set so after if else section $status = "NO" so your output table will contain rows with id="NO", and that's also a bad thing because id should be unique...

Comment: Also, in a DOM, ids shall be unique. You may use classes and `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code has wrong order (you're trying to read variables before they're even set). Therefore it gives undefined values.
Make sure you set the `$price` and `$status` before you pass them to the script.
Also don't use `id` as show/hide condition (as id have to be unique), use class instead.

```
<?php
  $price = 31;

  $prices = array ("20", "56", "33", "12", "66", "25", "55");
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  foreach ($prices as $price) {
    echo "<tr style='display:block;' class='".($price > 30 ? 'YES' : 'NO')."'><td>$price</td></tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function displayRow(){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("<?php echo ($price > 30 ? 'YES' : 'NO');?>");
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i+=1){
      if(elems[i].style.display == 'block'){
        elems[i].style.display = 'none';
      }else{
        elems[i].style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<button onClick="displayRow()" >Show / Hide</button>
```

Comment: This is excellent Phillip, a very elegant solution indeed!! I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code will generate multiple rows with the same id (Yes or No).  In HTML, there can be *only one* id, so maybe change this to class instead of id.

Second, I wouldn't "hide" the row via code.  If you are adding a class use CSS to hide the rows with the appropriate class.

Given: **HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Visible Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='dontshow'>
        <td>Invisible Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='hidethis'>
        <td>Visible Data, can change</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='hidethis'>
        <td>Visible Data, can change</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

And, **CSS**

```
.dontshow {
    display:none;
}
```

Try this to hide a row ...

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("hidethis");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].setAttribute("class", "hidethis dontshow");
}
```

... and something like this to display a row ...

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("hidethis");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].setAttribute("class", "hidethis");
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/o633c360/

I used jQuery in this example, SIMPLY to enable the click events faster.  You can just as easily use the onclick used in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayRow(){
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('NO');

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].style.display !== "none") {
           list[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       else {
           list[i].style.display = "inline-block";
       }
   }
}
</script>

<?php
    $prices = array ("20", "56", "33", "12", "66", "25", "55");
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    foreach ($prices as $price) {
       if($price >= 30.00) {
         $status = "YES";
       }else if ($price < 30.00) {
         $status = "NO";
       }
       echo "<tr class='$status' style="display:inline-block"><td>$price</td></tr>";
    } 
    echo "</table>";
?>

<button onclick="displayRow()" >Show / Hide</button>
```